# Gif Animation Opens up div box background on hover

Tags: html, css, xhtml

[image]

Image on the left what I want, on the right what I keep getting. Here is my code;

goo.gl/rnhJ7

```
<div id="butterbox">
    <div id="btrlwh">
        <div id="btrlan">
            <div id="btrlbx">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

div#butterbox {position:absolute;}
#btrlwh {background:url(/wp-content/themes/bliss/images/butterfly/leftwhite.gif) no-repeat;width:52px;height:50px;position:relative;right:75px;top:64px;padding:14px 0 0 2px;}
#btrlan {background:url(/wp-content/themes/bliss/images/butterfly/leftd.gif) no-repeat;width:52px;height:50px;z-index:999;}
#btrlan:hover {background:url(/wp-content/themes/bliss/images/butterfly/left.gif) no-repeat; }
#btrlbx {width:81px;height:58px;position:relative;top:15px;left:25px;border:1px solid #FFF;background-color:#8ad1e3;z-index:9;}
```

Comment: Which div do you want to open when hovering over btrlan and what will the size dimensions be of the opening box?

Comment: #btrlbx needs to open up. I actually would like to put opacity and width/height transition on it too. #btrlbx needs to open behind the butterfly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
#btrlbx {visibility:hidden}
#btrlan:hover #btrlbx {visibility:visible}
```

Comment: its showing up on butterfly. Its still not behind it.